# Creating table of variables with specific summary statistics

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr

I am trying to make a table of all my numerical variables (i.e. feature) in the following format:

```
Feature | Count | % Missing | Cardinality | Min. | 1st Quartile | Mean | Median | 3rd Quartile | Max. | Std. Dev. |
```

--------|-------|-----------|-------------|------|--------------|------|--------|--------------|------|-----------|
        |       |           |             |      |              |      |        |              |      |           |

So each row signifies a specific numeric variable and each column the statistics shown above (Count, % Missing, Cardinality, Min., 1st Quartile, Mean, Median, 3rd Quartile, Max. Std. Dev.)

Say my dataset is called Mashable and my numerical variables are called X, Y and Z. How would I create this table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `dplyr` already, you can make use of long shaped data and grouping, and treat all the functions you need as summarizations. That lets you scale easily, so it's the same workflow for 3 variables as it is for 25 or 100. It also makes it relatively quick to apply whatever functions you want.

I made dummy data with x, y, and z, then bound onto it a couple rows of `NA`s just to show the missing value count. Gather it to long data, group by the variable, then use whatever summary functions you want. I started out the first several you named. This gives you the format you asked for.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  x = rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 1),
  y = rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 1),
  z = rexp(100, rate = 0.01)
) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(x = c(NA, NA), y = c(NA, NA), z = c(NA, NA))) %>%
  gather(key = variable, value = value) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    missing = sum(is.na(value)),
    share_missing = missing / count,
    mean = mean(value, na.rm = T),
    sd = sd(value, na.rm = T),
    q1 = quantile(value, 0.25, na.rm = T)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>   variable count missing share_missing    mean     sd     q1
#>   <chr>    <int>   <int>         <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 x          102       2        0.0196   0.997  1.08   0.246
#> 2 y          102       2        0.0196   9.81   0.962  9.10 
#> 3 z          102       2        0.0196 106.    90.6   39.9
```

Created on 2018-05-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages transform your data. Let me take an example to demonstrate transformation for 3 statistics(e.g. `mean,median,sd`). You can add other statistics like `count`, `% missing` etc similar way.

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(X = 1:10, Y = 11:20, Z = 101:110)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% summarize_all(funs(mean,median,sd)) %>%  #Statistics for mean, median,sd
  gather(key, value) %>%    #Convert to long format
  separate(key, c("feature", "stat")) %>%  #separate out feature from function
  spread(stat, value)

#    feature  mean median      sd
# 1        X   5.5    5.5 3.02765
# 2        Y  15.5   15.5 3.02765
# 3        Z 105.5  105.5 3.02765
```

Answer (score 0):

If X, Y and Z are the columns of your dataset, then you could just use the `apply` function to each column in your dataset in R and this will print each of your required statistics e.g.:

```
apply(dat,2,function(x) c(length(which(is.na(x)==TRUE)),summary(x)))
```

I mean in general you would specify the data-frame in the first argument. Then select the rows/columns or list (e.g. 2 is column, 1 is row for a matrix/df) depending on the type of structure you are using the function on. And finally a function to apply to each of those rows/columns of list as specified in the prior argument. In this case we used the `c` function to output both the length of NA and a summary of the data (min, max, quartiles). By extension we can specify any argument here, so in general:

```
apply("Insert your data-frame","What part of the data-frame",function(x) c(a(x),b(x),...))
```

It would be preferable to read the R help file for any additional requirements!

Hope it helps; Cheers.